# Male Budgie doesn't want female in his cage

Tags: aggression, birds, socializing, cage, budgerigar

We recently got a female friend for our old male budgie. They are not doing much outside the cage. Right now they have separate cages. But the female wants to get inside the male's cage, I think because it's bigger. Unfortunately, the male keeps squawking at her even though she's just chilling in the corner so we always have to separate them. Will they get used to each other or should we give the female budgie back?

Answer (score 2):

It can take a long time for two birds to love each other and tolerate the presence of the other. It can range from a few days to several years! Above all, you must not force the birds to get along and let them move at their own pace.

What you can do is wait until they get along better and then start putting the male in the female's cage (it will no longer be the male who will be in the dominant position since he is in the "territory. "of the female). If the cohabitation goes well the next step will be to put them in the bigger cage.